# Intellisense missing when I step through code in a reference?

Tags: c#, intellisense

I'm debugging a C# project in VS 2012 Express.  Normally, when I step through the code, I'm able to use Intellisense in the Immediates window.  But when I step into a function from a referenced DLL, the Intellisense doesn't work.  What's more, I'm able to edit the code in the DLL's .cs file, whereas normally if I try to edit code while I'm debugging, I get an error message telling me that edits are not allowed while debugging.

Is this normal behavior for VS 2012 Express?

EDIT: I just tried removing and re-adding the reference, and that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What kind of project are we talking about? Silverlight, Winforms, WPF?

Comment: Is the DLL's cs file in the same project?

Comment: @Silvermind: It's a console app.

Comment: @gl3829: the DLL's cs file isn't in the same project AFAIK, as it doesn't appear in the main list of cs files in the Solution Explorer, but the file does open when I step into an object whose class is defined in the DLL.

Comment: There used to be something about 64-bit not allowing you to edit code.  You could try setting target to 32-bit (x86) to see if that helps at all?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone, I'm not trying to enable code editing in the project; it just seemed odd that editing the code wasn't causing the usual error message, and I was wondering if this is related to the Intellisense issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this, I've had other cases where I was able to use Intellisense while stepping through a function from a referenced DLL.  This doesn't appear to be consistent behavior, and is solvable by restarting Windows.  I'll repost a similar question if this behavior comes up again and I notice a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure that the `Build Action` of the .cs file is set to `Compile`.

Comment: @sigil - Are you set to `Debug` or `Release` mode?

Comment: @Ramhound, I was in Debug mode.  I switched to Release, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @sigil - Stay in debug mode, release mode, disables lots of features like this.  ALL of your solutions including the dll is set to Debug mode right?  You can't debug a Release mode dll for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, everything is set to Debug.